# react-native: switch from yarn to npm

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg

Is there a step-by-step process to change a react-native project from using yarn as the package manager to using npm? All I can find after several days of searching are instructions to go from npm to yarn and a package called [deyarn](https://github.com/mixmaxhq/deyarn) which doesn't seem to fully work for me. Does anyone have a good resource on this?

Comment: Please don't  change yarnpkg to yarn tag.
yarn is Yet Another Resource Negotiator, not is an open-source JavaScript package manager (use with yarnpkg tag).

Comment: What version of npm are you using?  yarn was created, I believe, to lock in module versions so that installing modules across systems was consistent.  NPM added this functionality in version 5, but if you're using an older version, then your "npm install" is grabbing the latest of everything (I think) and probably one of those packages are breaking your code.  yarn install on the other hand will install the same versions on both PCs (as will npm 5, but I've read not as good).  Should be able to use the versions in yarn.lock file in your package-lock.json file, in theory.

Answer (score 57):

Try this :

- Remove `yarn.lock` (don't need this file).
- Remove folder `node_modules`
- In `package.json`, change script use yarn to the same command with `npm`
- Remove all global package of `yarn` (don't need to remove if you want to use `npm` for one project)
- Remove `yarn` if you don't want to use it again.
- Install `npm` (if you installed, ignore this step)
- Install global and local package you need

Can you upload some `error`, you said that `not fully work`.

Edit:

If you want to change `npm` to `yarn`, it same:

- Remove `package-lock.json` (don't need this file).
- Remove folder `node_modules`
- In `package.json`, change script uses `npm` to the same command with `yarn`
- Remove all global package of `npm` (don't need to remove if you want to use `yarn` for one project)
- Remove `npm` if you don't want to use it again.
- Install `yarn` (if you installed, ignore this step)
- Install global and local package you need

You can see [CLI commands comparison](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm#toc-cli-commands-comparison) for 3rd step

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. I think the 'not fully working' part and the reason your suggestion does not work for me is due to some things in the gitignore file for the project. I will have to check and come back

Comment: ` it doesn't work`. Can you tell me why you said that ?

Comment: I said that because it does not work. I expect that when I run the command and follow your instructions, check in my code to git, do a fresh clone and try to do a fresh npm install I should be able run my project but I can't. The only way it will run is if I do a yarn install.

Comment: Your source code can be public, if true can you upload, I will try fix it.

Comment: @Hongarc If I need to add yarn to npm project?

Comment: @DevAS, your mean is use `yarn` and `npm` or change `npm` to `yarn`?

Comment: change npm to yarn

Comment: @Hongarc thank you, that's awesome, but if I use NPM and YARN in the same project that's mistake or normal

Comment: @DevAS, You can do it, but you should not do that. it is dangerous.

You and your team can't use the same version of all module(way to get the version of `yarn` and `npm` is different)

Answer (score 9):

You can try taking the following steps:

1. Remove `node_modules`
2. Run `npm install`

This should work because npm and yarn use the same package.json.

Answer (score 5):

The [deyarn](https://github.com/mixmaxhq/deyarn) package worked brilliantly for me.

Note that it will only flag (not auto-update) any package-lock.json scripts that you may need to update.

Depending on your environment needs, you may also want to strip out the `engines: yarn: '..'` entry it adds to your package-lock.json.

Comment: this is the best answer, because it takes care of the exact dependency versions, so that nothing breaks after new installation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything just run npm start cmd then follow the same step as suggest.

I've covert my yarn project To npm see the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWPtV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt0Ej.png)

hope is work for you.
thanks happy coding.