# NPM or Yarn? What is the standard practice of starting React Native projects and managing packages?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg, package-managers

When [starting a new React Native project](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) as below it's set up with yarn as it creates a *yarn.lock* file.

```
react-native init myProjectName
```

At the same time, many of the common libraries assume that that **NPM** is being used, like for example [this one](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing):

```
npm install --save react-native-navigation
```

Now having read many debates on this online (like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/976dxy/i_have_both_yarn_and_npm_installed_and_theyre/e46dbpt?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)), I gather that mixing the two is generally not a good idea, and the developer should stick to one of the other.

So... I decided to use **NPM** as that is something I am happy, familiar and comfortable with, and I haven't seen any delta which would justify switching to **Yarn** in my case. (Open to be convinced otherwise.)

**My Question:**

- Would it be the best practice in my case is to start a project with `react-native init myProjectName`, and then manually tear out the yarn parts as for example described by this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51255470/682778)? Or is there a better way of starting React Native projects using **NPM**?
- Should I just use Yarn instead, and install everything with that, because that's just the "real" React Native way, or for any other reasons?

I am looking to find out what the **best practice** is and stick to it from now on. If possible, I'd rather not burn more gas thinking about package management in the future.

Comment: there is no best practice. NPM had many problems (including performance) and yarn was created to address these problems. Since then, NPM fixed most of these problems, therefore it's a question why anybody would still use yarn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each has their own respective benefits.

**Yarn: Benefits**

- Considered faster than NPM
- Easy to use/stable
- Not too much of a departure from NPM

**Yarn: Drawbacks**

- Doesn't work with node v5 or older.
- **Has had issues when installing/compiling native modules.**
  Though I believe there are more [recent updates/workarounds](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5814).