# How do I remove yarn from angular cli. I want to use npm to install packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, yarnpkg

```
Installing packages for tooling via yarn.
An unhandled exception occurred: 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Package install failed, see above.
See "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-TAwQZJ\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

This is the error in my terminal everytime I try to install any package.

I have tried "npm uninstall -g yarn" nothing happens. I tried in control panel to find any yarn package but nothing.
How can we do this and install packages via npm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239726/react-native-switch-from-yarn-to-npm/51255470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try either of

```
ng config --global cli.packageManager npm
```

or

```
ng set --global packageManager=npm
```

Also, Yarn is faster and better as per some blogs,

So you can keep yarn as default package manager and install it

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/